# Find a minimum weighted spanning tree of the Cycle graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, minimum-spanning-tree

[image]

I'm trying to solve the problem presented above and here is my attempt:

**Attempt:** We can apply Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm instead of using Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms to find a MST as Dijkstra will visit all the nodes in the smallest weighted distance. Complexity: For G = (V,E), O(E log(V))

Questions:

(1) Is my approach correct ?
(2) Is it the most efficient answer to the question ?

If i'm completely wrong, I would appreciate a correct and efficient solution.

Comment: great attempt! now whats your question?

Comment: @RNar I've updated my post, but I thought it was self evident that I was looking for a correct and efficient solution if my approach is incorrect or not the most efficient.

Comment: Apart from those edges that form the cycle, are there any other edges?

Comment: How many edges are in the cycle graph? How many edges in a spanning tree? If you can answer those two questions, this problem should become trivial :)

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele N edges in a cycle graph, N - 1 edges in Tree. So just traverse the N - 1 edges, take eliminate the edge with maximum weight, the remaining path is the spanning tree ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm your answer is now correct. Iterating through **N** edges and eliminate the maximum-weight edge.

Comment: @PhamTrung Please write as answer so you can get the credit

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm you can write your own answer also.

Comment: Self-answering is OK, but you may want to credit Pham Trung in your answer, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cycle graph contains no edges other than those connecting the vertices in the cycle. So what we can do is iterate through all N edges and eliminate the maximum weighted edge forming a spanning tree of N - 1 edges containing the minimum sum of edges, forming a Minimum Spanning Tree.